# CSS -Menu work as <a href> with background not just text

Tags: html, css

my code of menu work fine, but only text is a href, how ever i try to make it a bit more user friendly so make even background in

to work as href but its not working, can somebody help me to fix it? 
My HTML:

```
 <div id="menu">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#">GAMESITES</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li><a href="#">HRY<span class="arrow"></a></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li><a href="#">SERVERY</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li><a href="#">CLANKY</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li><a href="#">FORUM</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li><a href="#">DOWNLOADS</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li><a href="#">BLOGY</a><span class="arrow"></span></li>
      <li class="spacer"> </li>
      <li>FLASHOVKY<span class="arrow"></span></li>                                                
    </ul> 
  </div>
```

My CSS:

```
    #menu{
        background-image: url("images/menubg.png");
        background-repeat: repeat-x;
        height: 44px;
        width: 983px;
        margin: 0 22px;          
    }

    .spacer{
        background-image: url("images/menu_spacer.png");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        width: 1px;
        height: 25px;
        margin: 0px 12px;
    }
#menu ul{
    list-style-position: inside;    /* Bodka v novom riadku vo vnutry */
    list-style-type: none;          /* bez bodky */
}

#menu ul li{   
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    color: #f7f7f7;
}

.arrow{
    background-image: url("images/sipka.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block; 
}
```

Live preview: http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/

Comment: Using the spacer element is unsemantic. What about assigning the spacer background to a pseudo-element added after each `<li>` element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your markup can be heavily simplified into this:

```
<div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">GAMESITES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">HRY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SERVERY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CLANKY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FORUM</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">DOWNLOADS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">BLOGY</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">FLASHOVKY</a></li>                                                
    </ul> 
</div>
```

### Flexbox solution

If you're willing to explore modern CSS specifications, you can always use flexbox instead of relying on inline-block to position your elements — check out the demo fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/9FZS8/

```
#menu {
    background-image: url(http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/images/menubg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    width: 983px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#menu ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#menu ul li {
    color: #f7f7f7;
    flex: 1 1 auto;
}
#menu ul li a {
    background-image: url(http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/images/menu_spacer.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    display: block;
    padding: 14px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li:last-child a {
    background: none;
}
#menu ul li a:after {
    background-image: url(http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/images/sipka.png);
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

---

### Non-Flexbox solution

Otherwise, you can always fallback to floating your individual `<a>` elements, but that requires you to calculate the padding for each of them carefully so the menu does not overflow: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/9FZS8/2/

```
#menu {
    background-image: url(http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/images/menubg.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 44px;
    width: 983px;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#menu ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#menu ul li {
    color: #f7f7f7;
}
#menu ul li a {
    background-image: url(http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/images/menu_spacer.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top right;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 15px; /* Disadvantage: you will have to adjust this padding MANUALLY */
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
}
#menu ul li:last-child a {
    background: none;
}
#menu ul li a:after {
    background-image: url(http://funedit.com/andurit/try4/images/sipka.png);
    content: '';
    width: 10px;
    height: 8px;
    margin-left: 8px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, your advise is really helpfull, ive got 1 more simple problem. I add min-width in #menu ul li a  to make it on full size of page, also try to margin / padding text a bit from left site but if i do this the href position is margin / padding too so not full size of background work as href

Comment: @user258459 I don't understand your question — can you please rephrase it?

Comment: menu background have lets say 1000px width, so i need to devide text on full width of it so i add min-width of each <li>  and then i notiecd text in too close to the endge on left site so i add margin-left: 20px for example but it alwose move click able a href part by 20px. And i need to fix it. Hope its understand able :( if not i can give u some live preview or something

Comment: Why not just add `padding-left: 20px` on the first `<a>`? Margins are always outside of the content-box, while padding is in.

Comment: i try padding as well, my menu ul li have : padding-left: 10px; in it and like firt 10 pixels of menu from left is not click able

Comment: You need to assign padding to the clickable element, i.e. `<a>`, **not the parent `<li>` element**.

Answer (score 1):

Add to your links a padding of x and a margin of -x, for example:

```
#menu a {
    padding: 20px;
    margin: -20px;
}
```

Comment: How this is going to fix to make whole <li> as a href?

Comment: The padding will make the active area of the link the same width and height than your button background, and the negative margin will keep it in the same position. See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/3et4t/ I've added a dotted border so you can see what the active area is.

Comment: You are right, it help a bit but as soon as text in menu is different lenght it cant be used

Comment: There's no problem with text length, because the active area would be 20px around the text, check it in the fiddle above, every link has a different width depending on text length.

Answer (score 0):

Make link to take full space:

```
li > a{
  display:inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the list-items dont'cover the full space between separators.

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan so make them to cover full space and inside li elements use some css to make visual spaces (if needed).